# Если есть определенный class на странице, то приписывать класс к другому блоку

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно добавить класс к определенному блоку, при условии, что на странице есть определенный класс.

Например

```
<body>
<div class="blok-1"</div>
<div class="test-1">[скрытый блок, который появляется, если есть на странице класс blok-1]</div>
</body>
```

Comment: CSS — `.block-1 + .test-1 { display: block; }` ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**jQuery**

```
if($('.blok-1').length > 0) {
  $('.test-1').addClass('show');
}
```

Пример:

```js
if ($('.blok-1').length > 0) {
  $('.test-1').addClass('show');
}
```

```css
.test-1 {
  display: none;
}

.test-1.show {
  display: block;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="blok-1"></div>
<div class="test-1">[скрытый блок, который появляется, если есть на странице класс blok-1]</div>
```

---

**Javascript**

```
if(document.getElementsByClassName('blok-1').length > 0) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('test-1')[0].classList.add('show');
}
```

Пример:

```js
if (document.getElementsByClassName('blok-1').length > 0) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('test-1')[0].classList.add('show');
}
```

```css
.test-1 {
  display: none;
}

.test-1.show {
  display: block;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="blok-1"></div>
<div class="test-1">[скрытый блок, который появляется, если есть на странице класс blok-1]</div>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Выручили!